# A gallery display formatter for Media

Tags: 7, entities, media

I'm using [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media), version 7.X, and I'm looking for a module that creates a display widget as a gallery for a "file" field.

I'v tried [Media Gallery](https://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) but I can't use "dev" versions.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can try to create your own formatter using [`hook_field_formatter_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and [`hook_field_formatter_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7). There's also loads of blogs on how to do this step-by-step if you search on Google. Such as [this](http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/create-custom-field-formatter-drupal-7)

Answer (score -1):

Create Block using views module and show in sidebar.

Comment: I know this solution, I need a display formatter. My question was another.